# Foursquare API Auth Token

Tags: php, javascript, foursquare

I have this api link from foursquare. Where can I get the oauth_token? I replace it with my client ID, it wouldn't work.

I want to do a search of venue when user key into the input and populate the link.

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/suggestCompletion?ll=40.7,-74&query=foursqu&oauth_token=5VCEWSVZZD5QN4OL1WF31IOZAAXS5PHEDKW2K1OCDLE24ICC&v=20130

Please enlighten.

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth.html) on how you can get your token.

Comment: Given: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=YYYYMMDD

What should be YYYMMDD ? Today's date?

Comment: That's for userless access. Try the endpoint for client access.

Comment: I am trying to do userless access. So that every client can search the location from their input.

Comment: Now, I learnt that oauth_token = access_token. But where can I get this? Please help :(

Answer (score 1):

To generate a Foursquare OAuth access token you have to go through the OAuth flow as described by Foursquare on this page: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth

One easy way to do this is to use the OAuth wrappers provided by [Temboo](http://temboo.com). They break the OAuth flow up into two simple steps:

`InitializeOAuth` - returns a Foursquare authorization URL that you can show to your users and have them grant your application access to their Foursquare account.

`FinalizeOAuth` - returns the access tokens your app needs for authenticated access to Foursquare accounts.

You can experiment with Temboo's Foursquare OAuth support in your browser from the link below, and then generate the source code you need to use this behavior in your app with the Temboo PHP SDK.

https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Foursquare/OAuth/

You can see an example of how Temboo handles OAuth for Facebook [here](http://temboo.com/examples). The full PHP source code is available (and adapting this to work for Foursquare is straightforward).

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo, so let me know if you have any questions!)

Comment: Thanks for the help. How about making this to use in Windows Phone 8? Any help?

Comment: We're working on a C# SDK at the moment, which will be released in a few weeks. That'll make it easy to use Temboo on Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

you can generate access token via following procedure given on https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth.html

or you can refer https://github.com/yikulju/Foursquare-on-node

check test > node-foursquare-test.js and lib > node-foursquare.js for more details

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to get the token :

```
 $client_key = "XXXXXXX";
    $client_secret = "XXXXXXX";
    $redirect_uri = "http://localhost/project/";

    $foursquare = new FoursquareApi($client_key,$client_secret);

    if(array_key_exists("code",$_GET)){
            $token = $foursquare->GetToken($_GET['code'],$redirect_uri);
        }

    if(!isset($token)){ 
            echo "<a href='".$foursquare->AuthenticationLink($redirect_uri)."'>Connect to this app via Foursquare</a>";
        // Otherwise display the token
        }else{
            echo "Your auth token: $token";
        }
```

Foursquare class:

```
    define("DEFAULT_VERSION", "20160322");

    class FoursquareApiException extends Exception {}

class FoursquareApi {



    /** @var String $BaseUrl The base url for the foursquare API */
        private $BaseUrl = "https://api.foursquare.com/";
        /** @var String $AuthUrl The url for obtaining the auth access code */
        private $AuthUrl = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate";
        /** @var String $AuthorizeUrl The url for obtaining an auth token, reprompting even if logged in */
        private $AuthorizeUrl = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authorize";
        /** @var String $TokenUrl The url for obtaining an auth token */
        private $TokenUrl = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token";

        // Edited Petr Babicka (babcca@gmail.com) https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning
        /** @var String $Version YYYYMMDD */
        private $Version;

        /** @var String $ClientID */
        private $ClientID;
        /** @var String $ClientSecret */
        private $ClientSecret;
        /** @var String $RedirectUri */
        protected $RedirectUri;
        /** @var String $AuthToken */
        private $AuthToken;
        /** @var String $ClientLanguage */
        private $ClientLanguage;
        /** @var String[] $ResponseHeaders */
        public $ResponseHeaders = array();
        /** @var String last url sent */
        public $LastUrl;

        /**
         * Constructor for the API
         * Prepares the request URL and client api params
         * @param bool|String $client_id
         * @param bool|String $client_secret
         * @param string $redirect_uri
         * @param String $version Defaults to v2, appends into the API url
         * @param string $language
         * @param string $api_version https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning
         */
        public function  __construct($client_id = false,$client_secret = false, $redirect_uri='', $version='v2', $language='en', $api_version=DEFAULT_VERSION){
            $this->BaseUrl = "{$this->BaseUrl}$version/";
            $this->ClientID = $client_id;
            $this->ClientSecret = $client_secret;
            $this->ClientLanguage = $language;
            $this->RedirectUri = $redirect_uri;
            $this->Version = $api_version;
        }

        public function setRedirectUri( $uri ) {
            $this->RedirectUri = $uri;
        }

        // Request functions

        /** 
         * GetPublic
         * Performs a request for a public resource
         * @param String $endpoint A particular endpoint of the Foursquare API
         * @param Array $params A set of parameters to be appended to the request, defaults to false (none)
         */
        public function GetPublic($endpoint,$params=false){
            // Build the endpoint URL
            $url = $this->BaseUrl . trim($endpoint,"/");
            // Append the client details
            $params['client_id'] = $this->ClientID;
            $params['client_secret'] = $this->ClientSecret;
            $params['v'] = $this->Version;
            $params['locale'] = $this->ClientLanguage;
            // Return the result;
            return $this->GET($url,$params);
        }

        /** 
         * GetPrivate
         * Performs a request for a private resource
         * @param String $endpoint A particular endpoint of the Foursquare API
         * @param Array $params A set of parameters to be appended to the request, defaults to false (none)
         * @param bool $POST whether or not to use a POST request
         */
        public function GetPrivate($endpoint,$params=false,$POST=false){
            $url = $this->BaseUrl . trim($endpoint,"/");
            $params['oauth_token'] = $this->AuthToken;
            $params['v'] = $this->Version;
            $params['locale'] = $this->ClientLanguage;
            if(!$POST) return $this->GET($url,$params);
            else return $this->POST($url,$params);
        }

        /**
         * GetMulti
         * Performs a request for up to 5 private or public resources
         * @param Array $requests An array of arrays containing the endpoint and a set of parameters
         * to be appended to the request, defaults to false (none)
         * @param bool $POST whether or not to use a POST request, e.g.  for large request bodies.
         * It does not allow you to call endpoints that mutate data.
         */
        public function GetMulti($requests=false,$POST=false){
            $url = $this->BaseUrl . "multi";        
            $params = array();
            $params['oauth_token'] = $this->AuthToken;
            $params['v'] = $this->Version;      
            if (is_array($requests)){
                $request_queries = array();
                foreach($requests as $request) {
                    $endpoint = $request['endpoint'];
                    unset($request['endpoint']);
                    $query = '/' . $endpoint;
                        if (!empty($request)) $query .= '?' . http_build_query($request);
                    $request_queries[] = $query;
                }
                $params['requests'] = implode(',', $request_queries);
            }
                    if(!$POST) return $this->GET($url,$params);
            else return $this->POST($url,$params);
        }

        public function getResponseFromJsonString($json) {
            $json = json_decode( $json );
            if ( !isset( $json->response ) ) {
                throw new FoursquareApiException( 'Invalid response' );
            }

            // Better to check status code and fail gracefully, but not worried about it
            // ... REALLY, we should be checking the HTTP status code as well, not 
            // just what the API gives us in it's microformat
            /*
            if ( !isset( $json->meta->code ) || 200 !== $json->meta->code ) {
                throw new FoursquareApiException( 'Invalid response' );
            }
            */
            return $json->response;
        }

        /**
         * Request
         * Performs a cUrl request with a url generated by MakeUrl. The useragent of the request is hardcoded
         * as the Google Chrome Browser agent
         * @param String $url The base url to query
         * @param Array $params The parameters to pass to the request
         */
        private function Request($url, $params=false, $type=HTTP_GET){

            // Populate data for the GET request
            if($type == HTTP_GET) $url = $this->MakeUrl($url,$params);

            $this->LastUrl = $url;

            // Reset the headers every time we initiate a new request
            $this->ResponseHeaders = array();

            // borrowed from Andy Langton: http://andylangton.co.uk/
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
            } else {
                // Handle the useragent like we are Google Chrome
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.X.Y.Z Safari/525.13.');
            }
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);//---------------------SSL verification disable
            $acceptLanguage[] = "Accept-Language:" . $this->ClientLanguage;
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $acceptLanguage);
            // Set the header callback
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array($this, 'ParseHeaders'));
            // Populate the data for POST
            if($type == HTTP_POST) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
                if($params) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
            }

            $result=curl_exec($ch);
            $info=curl_getinfo($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            return $result;
        }

        /**
         * Callback function to handle header strings as they are returned by cUrl in the $this->Request() function
         * Parses header strings into key/value pairs and stores them in $ResponseHeaders array
         *
         * @param $ch
         * @param $header
         * @return int
         */
        private function ParseHeaders($ch, $header) {
            if (strpos($header, ':') !== false) {
                $header_split = explode(':', $header);
                $this->ResponseHeaders[strtolower(trim($header_split[0]))] = trim($header_split[1]);
            }
            return strlen($header);
        }

        /**
         * GET
         * Abstraction of the GET request
         */
        private function GET($url,$params=false){
            return $this->Request($url,$params,HTTP_GET);
        }

        /**
         * POST
         * Abstraction of a POST request
         */
        private function POST($url,$params=false){
            return $this->Request($url,$params,HTTP_POST);
        }


        // Helper Functions

        /**
         * GeoLocate
         * Leverages the google maps api to generate a lat/lng pair for a given address
         * packaged with FoursquareApi to facilitate locality searches.
         * @param String $addr An address string accepted by the google maps api
         * @return array(lat, lng) || NULL
         */
        public function GeoLocate($addr){
            $geoapi = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";
            $params = array("address"=>$addr,"sensor"=>"false");
            $response = $this->GET($geoapi,$params);
            $json = json_decode($response);
            if ($json->status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                return null;
            } else {
                return array($json->results[0]->geometry->location->lat,$json->results[0]->geometry->location->lng);
            }
        }

        /**
         * MakeUrl
         * Takes a base url and an array of parameters and sanitizes the data, then creates a complete
         * url with each parameter as a GET parameter in the URL
         * @param String $url The base URL to append the query string to (without any query data)
         * @param Array $params The parameters to pass to the URL
         */ 
        private function MakeUrl($url,$params){
            return trim($url) . '?' . http_build_query($params); 
        }

        // Access token functions

        /**
         * SetAccessToken
         * Basic setter function, provides an authentication token to GetPrivate requests
         * @param String $token A Foursquare user auth_token
         */
        public function SetAccessToken($token){
            $this->AuthToken = $token;
        }

        /**
         * AuthenticationLink
         * Returns a link to the Foursquare web authentication page.
         * @param String $redirect The configured redirect_uri for the provided client credentials
         */
        public function AuthenticationLink($redirect=''){
            if ( 0 === strlen( $redirect ) ) {
                $redirect = $this->RedirectUri;
            }
            $params = array("client_id"=>$this->ClientID,"response_type"=>"code","redirect_uri"=>$redirect);
            return $this->MakeUrl($this->AuthUrl,$params);
        }

      /**
       * AuthorizeLink
       * Returns a link to the Foursquare web authentication page. Using /authorize will ask the user to
       * re-authenticate their identity and reauthorize your app while giving the user the option to
       * login under a different account.
       * @param String $redirect The configured redirect_uri for the provided client credentials
       */
      public function AuthorizeLink($redirect=''){
        if ( 0 === strlen( $redirect ) ) {
          $redirect = $this->RedirectUri;
        }
        $params = array("client_id"=>$this->ClientID,"response_type"=>"code","redirect_uri"=>$redirect);
        return $this->MakeUrl($this->AuthorizeUrl,$params);
      }

        /**
         * GetToken
         * Performs a request to Foursquare for a user token, and returns the token, while also storing it
         * locally for use in private requests
         * @param $code The 'code' parameter provided by the Foursquare webauth callback redirect
         * @param $redirect The configured redirect_uri for the provided client credentials
         */
        public function GetToken($code,$redirect=''){
            if ( 0 === strlen( $redirect ) ) {
                // If we have to use the same URI to request a token as we did for 
                // the authorization link, why are we not storing it internally?
                $redirect = $this->RedirectUri;
            }
            $params = array("client_id"=>$this->ClientID,
                            "client_secret"=>$this->ClientSecret,
                            "grant_type"=>"authorization_code",
                            "redirect_uri"=>$redirect,
                            "code"=>$code);
            $result = $this->GET($this->TokenUrl,$params);
            $json = json_decode($result);


            // Check if we get token
            if (property_exists($json, 'access_token')) {
                $this->SetAccessToken($json->access_token);
                return $json->access_token;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        /**
        *GetUserInfo
        *Request for user information
        *
        */
        public function GetUserInfo(){

        }
    }
```